# Templating/rendering properties in an empty array in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

http://jsfiddle.net/48yh14c3/

```
this.list = [
 {
  property: [{anotherProp: true}]
 },
 {
  property: []
 },
 {
  property: [{anotherProp: false}]
 }
]
```

In angular 1 you could reference deep properties and (for the most part) it would keep on rocking:

```
<div ng-repeat='thing in ctrl.list'>
   {{thing.property[0].anotherProp}}
</div>
```

I'm sure I could just *ngIf the parent property to make sure it exists, or flatten the original POJO. Just wondering if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the [Elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators):

```
<div *ngFor='#thing of list'>
   {{thing.property[0]?.anotherProp}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AdW5qVWiQVk3TiqxkXUu?p=preview)</kbd>