# Angular 2: how do I get some data from nested json objects?

Tags: json, angular

I want to show the street of a person. But it didn't work with the code that I have. I think I do it wrong. (to get the name of a person works perfectly)
json file:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name": "someName",
  "address":{
      "street":"someStreet",
      "number":"10"
  }
}
```

service get json:

```
 public getPerson(id:string):Observable<Person> {
               return this.http.get(PersonService.PATH + id + '.json')
                  .map((res:Response) => res.json());
        }
```

typescript file PersonDetail:

```
@Component({
    selector: "person",
    template: `
        <h3>Detail of {{person.name}}</h3> --> this works
        <p>{{person.address.street}}</p> --> this not
                  `
})
export class PersonDetail {
    private person:Person = Person.createEmptyPerson();
    private router:Router;

    constructor(personService:PersonService, params:RouteParams, router:Router) {
        personService.getItem(params.get("id")).subscribe((person:Person) => {
            this.person =person;
        });
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Person:

```
import {Address} from "./address";
export class Person {
    id:number;
    name:string;
   adress:Address;


    constructor(id:number, name:string, adress:Address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.adress = adress;
    }


    public static createEmptyPerson():Person{
        return new Person(0, "",null);
    }

}
```

Addres:

```
export class Address {
    street:string;
    number:number;


    constructor(street:string, number:number) {
        this.street = street;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public static createEmptyAddress():Address {
        return new Address("",0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `person.address` is set?

Comment: how do you mean?
Do I have to set person.address in PersonDetail class?

Comment: What is shown when you change `<p>{{person.address.street}}</p> ` to `<p>{{person.address}}</p>`? Does this output anything?

Comment: nothing, the div is empty

Comment: There might be a problem with creating the `person` instance.

Comment: maybe I do it wrong. Is there an other way to make a Person class based on the json file? I mean not with an other Class Address.

Comment: I don't know about that part. I only use Dart and this works a bit differently here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343644/4933038

Comment: You can debug your output in template with: {{ person | json }} to see what you get. Otherwise you should use Interfaces, not Classes for Person, with {{person?.name}} notation ( to avoid errors )

Answer (score 2):

I think that it works at the beginning for `person.name` because you create an empty person within your `PersonDetail` component. But not for address because the corresponding address is null:

```
public static createEmptyPerson():Person{
  return new Person(0, '',null);
}
```

Since HTTP requests are asynchronous, the complete data for the person will be there later.

I see two solutions for your problem:

- Use an `ngIf` around your template content:

  ```
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="person">
      <h3>Detail of {{person.name}}</h3>
      <p>{{person.address.street}}</p>
    </div>
  `
  ```
- As suggested by Eric, use the Elvis operator. But `Detail of` with nothing after will be displayed.

  ```
  template: `
    <h3>Detail of {{person?.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{person?.address?.street}}</p>
  `
  ```

Comment: I think my service class don't get my address from a person. How can I do that?

Comment: Got a problem in this kind, even if the data is present (I checked with console.log), what finally works is the Evlis operator around nested object

Comment: @MohamedB : I'm also facing the same issue. Could you resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have a typo on your Person class?

```
adress:Address
```

I believe it should be

```
address:Address
```